# Use SystemJS for development and webpack for production

Tags: angular, webpack, systemjs, production

I am trying to use both at the same time but I don't know how to do that.

I've got a file called `index.html` in /dev containing my systemjs code:

```
<!-- ... -->
<script src="config/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import("app").catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
</script>
<!-- ... -->
```

And then I let the `/index.html` get generated by webpack.

The problem I have is that webpack can't find assets or templates that I specify in a way that SystemJS can load them:

```
@Component({
    selector: "footer",
    templateUrl: "app/templates/structure/footer.html",
    styleUrls: ["assets/stylesheets/footer.min.css"]
})
export class FooterComponent {
}
```

I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
'./assets/stylesheets/footer.min.css' in 'MyVeryVeryLongPath\app\components\structure'
```

How do I make it possible for both webpack and SystemJS to find the file?

I think it might be related to the angular2-template-loader.

Update:
As I was suspecting the issue I'm having is related to the angular2-template loader. To be more precise this is the issue I have: https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader/issues/20

Comment: Why you want to use the both of them? (what is the benefit you will get from it?)

Comment: The benefit is that I don't have to have the webpack development server running in the background while developing.

Comment: @CryNickSystems, you can use `webpack --inline --colors --progress --display-error-details --display-cached` (if webpack is installed global), and the `webpack-dev-server` will not be run.

Comment: @ktretyak thanks for your suggestion. But that would still mean that for a simple change I'd have to wait a few seconds (if not dozens of seconds) for them to be "visible".